# How to correctly use lm for Regression in R

Tags: r

I'm attempting to run a regression on a dataset for a class exercise.

The dataset is broken in two columns, X and Y, with NA values scattered about.

Running the regression with the lm() call produces the following error:

```
lm(formula = Y ~ X, data = data2)
Error in lm.fit(x, y, offset = offset, singular.ok = singular.ok, ...) : 
  NA/NaN/Inf in 'y'
In addition: Warning message:
In storage.mode(v) <- "double" : NAs introduced by coercion
```

I first began experiencing this error and read it could be due to the NA values within the data, so I attempted to remove them on import using the follow method.

```
> library(readxl)
> data2 <- read_excel("data2.xlsx", na = "0")
```

That got my data loaded in seemingly successfully, however when I use View() I can still see the NA values within my data, running the regression with "lm(formula = Y ~ X, data = data2)" produces the same result.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks for taking the time to read the post.

Answer (score 0):

Probably your variable `Y` is not numeric, check its type with `str(data2)`.

Comment: Looks like you're right Vinícius, running str(data2) produced the following: 
> str(data2)
tibble [80 × 2] (S3: tbl_df/tbl/data.frame)
 $ X: chr [1:80] "55" "51" "99" "85" ...
 $ Y: chr [1:80] "21" "28" "NA" "17" ...

Any advice on how to many the transition to numeric eloquently?

Comment: You can use `as.numeric`